# What is the difference between like vs contains in visual basic

Tags: vb.net

I have this code:

```
 If (string1 Like string2) AND string3.Contains(string4) Then
```

What is the difference of both?

I thought like is a contains but I am not sure... being a C# code.

Comment: Like usually involves a pattern or wildcards: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/swf8kaxw.aspx

Comment: [`Like`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/swf8kaxw.aspx) vs. [`Contains`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dy85x1sa(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking a look at [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/swf8kaxw.aspx), it would appear that the `Like` keyword has a bit more comparison logic than a simple `.Contains()` operation.  The second string in the `Like` operation isn't just a string, but a *pattern* (like a regular expression).  For example:

```
testCheck = "F" Like "[A-Z]"
```

In this operation `testCheck` will evaluate to `True` because the first string matches (or is included in) the pattern identified by the second string.

Answer (score 1):

Like is more powerful as using pattern: http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/swf8kaxw.aspx (Compares a string against a pattern)

```
? Any single character

* Zero or more characters

# Any single digit (0–9)

[ charlist ] Any single character in charlist

[! charlist ] Any single character not in charlist
```